# How to read dynamic ASP TextBox (runat server), if this is created on Postback not on PageLoad

Tags: c#

Can we read a dynamic text box, which is created on first PostBack and not on PageLoad.

I have one form with a drop down field, when I choose item from that drop down and press a button then my dynamic fields are created. I want to read them with click on another server button. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get a handle on the dynamically-created textbox with code like this:

```
TextBox txtDynamic = (TextBox)(pnlParent.FindControl("txtDynamicId"));
```

The event handler in which you're trying to access the textbox will be running in a thread which has permission to access it.

Comment: I think you have missed the point. OP wrote - "**which is created on first PostBack and not on PageLoad**... **press a button then my dynamic fields are created**". ok, so far so good, thats a fisrt postback and  dynamic text box is created. however OP wants to "**I want to read them with click on another server button**". clicking a button (runat=server) starts another postback (second in order). during (after) second postback there will be no "dynamic text box" to access it...

Comment: Like Niko sayed, I don't see dynamic field after second post back and so i don't have any value in, because it doesn't exist. Any way I have save the problem with JavaScript function on client side. I hope.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to read data from a control that will not be recreated, you have to save the data. I suggest to use Viewstate ([MSDN LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)) and/or Session variables ([MSDN LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks for answer I will try that in the future, for now I will use JavaScript and send data from server to client and back.